# $a \geq \frac{1}{4}$ prove that $ab(1-a^2b) \leq 1$

Tags: inequality

for all a,b $\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \geq \frac{1}{4}$
prove that
$ab(1-a^2b) \leq 1$

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your works and thoughts on the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rewrite it as
$$(\frac{ab}{2}-1)^2+(a-\frac{1}{4})(ab)^2 \ge 0$$
which is trivial

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to

$$a^3b^2 - ab + 1 \ge 0$$

If you view this as a quadratic function of $b$, and compute the discriminant $D$, you will see that it's non-positive when $a \ge 1/4$

$D = a^2(1-4a) \le 0$

This proves the statement because the coefficient before $b^2$ in the quadratic function is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Let $ab=x$ then we have to prove that $ax^2-x+1\ge0.$

The minimum of this quadratic occurs at $x=\frac{1}{2a}$ and is $1-\frac{1}{4a}\ge 0.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $ab=x$, then
$$ab-a^3b^2-1\le 0 \implies ax^2-x+1 \ge 0, \forall x \in R$$
$$\implies (B^2-4AC)\le 0 \implies a\ge 1/4.$$